# Display posts in three columns by category

Tags: posts, categories, columns

I've seen posts which probably answer this, but unfortunately the answers are all a bit technical without telling you where the code should go?
At the moment I have my posts directed to a blog page. I separate my posts into three categories. What I would like is to have 3 columns for each category, with the ability to put an image and title above the start of each column, and a styled line between them.
I understand that this involves Loops and editing the php files, but in other posts they don't say which php files or which css etc? 
Sorry for being stupid, but if possible a simple explanation would be great. I'm using the free pagelines theme, but on a localhost as just learning.
Thanks very much!!

Comment: You can do this with a few lines of CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the theme you're using, but that ought to be irrelevant anyhow.

Pages can be assigned [template files](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates), the php of which defines what and how content is displayed on said page.

You do not need to modify the page templates supplied with the theme, instead create your own in addition to the ones existing already (for reference read the linked codex page). Assign that to the page set as blog page.

Whether you decide to run three separate loops or fetch the posts in one query sorted by categories (and echo markup accordingly from within the loop) is pretty much up to you. As for how to go about said loop(s) see the codex on the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class and its usage.

Whether you enqueue a separate style sheet for it or edit the themes *style.css* file is again up to you.

Should the original theme author ship regular updates and you be planning on making use of these in the future, you might want to decide not to modify it at all, but to familiarize yourself with [child themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) instead.

Comment: Read the three supplied codex articles and give it a go. Should you encounter more specific problems on the way, feel free to supply some info on your progress, show your research efforts and ask a less generic question. Welcome to WPSE and good luck.

Comment: Thanks very much for these answers - I'll give the suggestions a go!

Comment: Hi again. Using those links I've managed to get something that sort of works:

Comment: Thanks again Johannes. Using `code` <?php query_posts('category_name=Cat1');?> `/code` etc I've been able to list the posts in columns. However, I'm having trouble getting the posts to only display a few hundred words and then "read more...". I'm also not too sure how to head each section of posts with the category title and an image, and separate each column with a line? Everything I try just gives a php error in the browser.

Comment: You can control the excerpt length using a filter and control which categories it applies to on specific pages using conditionals tags http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

Comment: Don't use query_posts http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts

Answer (score 1):

You can do similar to the structure of below snippets in your free pagelines theme, here I'm using bootstrap to display it in three columns.

Just follow the same basic structure and apply it to the theme you have, and from their I think it may help you display different category in three columns.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s4">
    <?php  
      $args    = array( 'posts_per_page' => 8, 'category_name' => 'your-category' );
      $myposts = get_posts( $args );
      foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
        if (have_posts()) {
          the_title();
          get_the_content();
          // and other function in the_loop
        }
      endforeach;
      wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
  </div>
  <div class="col s4">
    <?php  
      $args    = array( 'posts_per_page' => 8, 'category_name' => 'your-category' );
      $myposts = get_posts( $args );
      foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
        if (have_posts()) {
          the_title();
          get_the_content();
          // and other function in the_loop
        }
      endforeach;
      wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
  </div>
  <div class="col s4">
    <?php  
      $args    = array( 'posts_per_page' => 8, 'category_name' => 'your-category' );
      $myposts = get_posts( $args );
      foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
        if (have_posts()) {
          the_title();
          get_the_content();
          // and other function in the_loop
        }
      endforeach;
      wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please take time to read from their official documentation of wordpress in this link

https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: How would I implement WP_query directly into the above code, rather than using get_posts but output the same?

Comment: Also, why would I in this instance use just get_posts rather than WP_Query, or vice versa? I think I need some clarity on why one would suit better than the other...